# Replacing two property values in array object and creating new array

Tags: javascript

***EDIT I should have been provided a more clear question and provided better data.

I need to take an existing array of objects, replace the names depending on two different id's, and create a new array out of them.

My JSON:

```
const legendData = [{

     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
 {
     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 8,
     "name": "Barings",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 5,
     "name": "BlackRock",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
}]
```

I need the AIM Derivatives names to change to the below, however, keep the rest the same.

```
const = legendData[{
     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives ODIN",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
 {
     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives CMF",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 8,
     "name": "Barings",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 5,
     "name": "BlackRock",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
}]
```

I got halfway with my code below, however, don't know how to combine both. The below only changes if the fileTypeId is 1 but not 2.

```
const newArr = legendData.map(item => item.assetManagerId === 11 && item.fileTypeId === 1? {
            ...item, name: "AIM Derivatives ODIN"
            } : item)

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`. While you will map, you can get desired name by `fileTypeId` from object which contains desired name:

```js
let arr = [{
    "assetManagerId": 11,
    "name": "AIM Derivatives",
    "fileTypeId": 1,

  },
  {
    "assetManagerId": 11,
    "name": "AIM Derivatives",
    "fileTypeId": 2,
  }]
const names = {1: 'AIM Derivatives ODIN', 2:'AIM Derivatives CMF'}

const result = arr.map(({name, fileTypeId, ...rest}) => 
    ({name: names[fileTypeId], fileTypeId, ...rest}))
console.log(result)
```

**UPDATE:**

```js
let arr = [{    "assetManagerId": 11,    "name": "AIM Derivatives",    "fileTypeId": 1},{
    "assetManagerId": 11,    "name": "AIM Derivatives",    "fileTypeId": 2,
},
{
    "assetManagerId": 8,    "name": "Barings",    "fileTypeId": 2,
},
{
    "assetManagerId": 5,    "name": "BlackRock",    "fileTypeId": 1,
}]
const names = {'AIM Derivatives': { 1: 'AIM Derivatives ODIN', 2:'AIM Derivatives CMF'}}
const result = arr.map(({name, fileTypeId, ...rest}) =>
    ({
        name: names[name] ? names[name][fileTypeId] : name,
        fileTypeId,
        ...rest
    }))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary and store the `fileTypeId` and relevant text

```js
const legendData = [{
    "assetManagerId": 11,
    "name": "AIM Derivatives",
    "fileTypeId": 1,

  },
  {
    "assetManagerId": 11,
    "name": "AIM Derivatives",
    "fileTypeId": 2,
  }
]
const idMap = {
  1: "AIM Derivatives ODIN",
  2: "AIM Derivatives CMF"
}
   // check if the assetManagerId matches and if the `fileTypeId` is one of the key in dictionary
const newArr = legendData.map(item => item.assetManagerId === 11 && idMap[item.fileTypeId] ? {
  ...item,
  // if one of the key the get the relevant value of that key
  name: idMap[item.fileTypeId]
} : item)
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: This answer works fine. Sorry for the confusion but I just updated the issue with an updated JSON (my fault). There will be more than one object in the array. Only AIM Derivatives should change. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could to try with a json config that keys are `assetManagerId` and `fileTypeId` and values are the new name.

```js
const newNamesConfig = {
  11: {
    1: { name: 'AIM Derivatives ODIN' },
    2: { name: 'AIM Derivatives CMF' },
  },
}
const derivatesNames = [{
  "assetManagerId": 11,
  "name": "AIM Derivatives",
  "fileTypeId": 1,

},
{
  "assetManagerId": 11,
  "name": "AIM Derivatives",
  "fileTypeId": 2,
}];


const renamedArray = derivatesNames.map(derivate => Object.assign({}, derivate,newNamesConfig[derivate.assetManagerId][derivate.fileTypeId]));
  
console.log(renamedArray)
```